# I keep getting the error "relation [TABLE] does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have been trying to query two tables in my database. In the server explorer I can see both tables and even see the columns within them. We'll call them Schema.table1 and Schema.table2 where "Schema" has its first letter capitalized. I have tried running the following queries:

```
select * from Schema.table1;
```

Where I get the following error:

> ERROR: relation "schema.table1" does not exist

I then tried running the next query thinking maybe the capitalization in the schema made a difference.

```
Select * from "Schema.table1"; 
select "ID" from "Schema.table1";
```

But the same error persisted:

> ERROR: relation "Schema.table1" does not exist

I later tried to specify the schema path with "SET search_path to "Schema1" and ran a query on the tables which again provided me the same error. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The table does exist. I can see it in the server explorer and even view all of the columns. It's there.

Comment: Each element of an identifier needs to be quoted: `"Schema"."table1"`

Comment: Is it Schema1 or Schema?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name has solved the issue. thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each element has to be quoted individually:

```
select "ID" 
from "Schema"."table1";
```

More details about quoted identifiers are [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)